# Save form data to SESSION variables before submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms, session-variables

I have a form to submit data and I am using the following code for session variables

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
} 
if (isset($_SESSION['product'])) {
    $product = $_SESSION['product'];
    if($product == "loan"){$loan='selected="selected"';} else {$loan='';}
    if($product == "card"){$card='selected="selected"';} else {$card='';}
    if($product == "savings"){$savings='selected="selected"';} else {$savings='';}
    if($product == "morgage"){$mortgage='selected="selected"';} else {$mortgage='';}
} else { $loan = $card = $savings = $mortgage = '';}
if (isset($_SESSION['liked'])) {
    $liked = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars(($_SESSION['liked'])));
} else {
    $liked = '';
}
if (isset($_SESSION['disliked'])) {
    $disliked = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars(($_SESSION['disliked'])));
} else {
    $disliked = '';
}
```

The form is something like this

```
        <form id="msform" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
        <label for="product">Select product:</label>
          <select name="product" id="product">
              <option value="loan" '. $loan .'>Personal Loan</option>
              <option value="card" '. $card .'>Credit Card</option>
              <option value="savings" '. $savings .'>Savings Account</option>
              <option value="mortgage" '. $mortgage .'>Mortgage</option>
            </select> 
        <textarea rows="4" name="liked" placeholder="I really liked...">'. $liked .'</textarea>
        <textarea rows="4" name="disliked" placeholder="I did not like...">'. $disliked .'</textarea>

        <!-- php if statements here, if logged in show submit button if not show Facebook login button -->

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>
```

The submit button is shown only to logged in users. If the user is not logged in a Facebook login button is shown. When he clicks on that he is sent to Facebook where if he accepts permissions of the app he is redirected back to the form as a logged in user. But then, all fields have been cleared. How can I save data to the session variables and repopulate it, if the GET/POST is not called yet?

Comment: Where does the user go when he clicks the **Facebook Login Button**? 


Make the **Facebook Login Button** a submit button with a `formaction` attribute to a *PHP* page where you would save the form inputs to `$_SESSION` and then redirect user to facebook to complete the login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of improving your code a bit.

Take a look at the following code snippet. This will add your form data to a session and keep it available even if the page is refreshed.

```
<?php
// First, we'll check if the session is set. Otherwise, we'll set it
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start(); 
}

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([/* . . . */]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $permissions);

// Is the form submitted? Add the formData to our session
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $_SESSION['formData'] = $_POST;
    unset($_POST);

    // If the user is not logged in, redirect them to the facebook login
    if (!$loggedIn) {
        header("location: " . $loginUrl);
        exit;
    }
}

// Predefine our select dropdown values
$options = [
    'loan' => 'Personal Loan',
    'card' => 'Credit Card',
    'savings' => 'Savings Account',
    'mortgage' => 'Mortgage',
];
?>

<!-- Your form -->
<form id="msform" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
        <label for="product">Select product:</label>
    <select name="product" id="product">
        <?php foreach ($options as $option => $optionValue): ?>
        <option value="<?= $option; ?>" <?= isset($_SESSION['formData']['product']) && $_SESSION['formData']['product'] == $option ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?= $optionValue; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <textarea rows="4" name="liked" placeholder="I really liked..."><?= isset($_SESSION['formData']['liked'] ? $_SESSION['formData']['liked'] : ''; ?></textarea>
    <textarea rows="4" name="disliked" placeholder="I did not like..."><?= isset($_SESSION['formData']['disliked']) ? $_SESSION['formData']['disliked'] : ''; ?></textarea>
    <?php if ($loggedIn): ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>
    <?php else: ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Login with Facebook"/>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to me that your code adds data to session after the submit button has been clicked. However, my question is how to store the data in session before POST since a logged out user does not see the submit button.

Comment: Ahh.. I understand. Well, you're not going to be able to do that in PHP without posting the form. What you're looking for is Javascript.

Comment: @GeorgeP Take a look at my edited answer. I am not sure if Facebook supports this method, but it's worth a try. This way you'll get best of both sides.

Comment: I see your point. I might try that. But, I would be prefer a way to save data in session almost instantly or as user types, using JavaScript. Again, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to store FormData in memory which can be later used for repopulation of fields. For this it would be better to use LocalStorage rather than SessionStorage. The LocalStorage API is documented here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Why? Just use session vars on the server

Comment: @mplungjan I must have misunderstood the question. The user is going to be redirected to a different domain, and then when he comes back we want the form to be repopulated. Wouldn't it be easier to store the form data to Local Storage and then use that object to repopulate the fields.

Comment: Except not great on a public server - and if on the client why not sessionStorage  instead of localStorage

Comment: My mistake...I didnt know sessionStorage persists even after switching domains as long as you are back on the same domain.